# How to correctly install python-numpy in Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, scipy, python-2.7

According to Scipy website, in Ubuntu 11.10 numpy and scipy comes pre-packaged so what I did was:

```
apt-get install python2.7
apt-get install python-numpy
apt-get install python-scipy
```

Then I tried to call numpy in Python but get an error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name datetime_data.
```

Any ideas why this happened? Full error message attached.

---

```
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:03:08)
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
    import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from type_check import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numerictypes as nt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/numerictypes.py", line 92, in <module>
    from numpy.core.multiarray import typeinfo, ndarray, array, \
ImportError: cannot import name datetime_data
```

Comment: I would really recommend using pip for your python dependancy management.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have a broken numpy install in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, the package manager installs numpy to /usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7

You should remove the broken numpy

```
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy
```

then the numpy you installed with `apt-get` should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after upgrading my numpy version. I solved it reinstalling and removing the numpy lib folder (for your python version)

```
sudo apt-get remove python-numpy
sudo rm -r /usr/local/lib/pythonX.X/dist-packages/numpy
sudo apt-get install python-numpy
```

(or installing a new numpy version from any numpy package)